# Replace a sequence of Numbers using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a sequence fragment  "123", in a number sequence such as 12312345435 and remove the repetitive sequence of 123 from the start. So after the replace the new number sequence would be like: 12345435. I might also have 123123123123, but I would like to trim the first occurrence of 123 from the sequence and leave the remaining untouched. How to do this using regex in Javascript?

Comment: What output do you expect for `"123123123123"`?   `"123123123"`?

Comment: Is this a trick question?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Please have a look on [regular expression fundamentals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to get a basic understanding.

Comment: @Engineer: Yes that's the outcome I am expecting. That case hold true and also the case when 123123999999 should be trimmed to 123999999.

Comment: `"12312344999999".replace(/123/,"").replace(/999/,"") === "12344999"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply use the following RegExp:

```
Txt.replace(/123((123)+)/,"$1");
```

That regex matches any string containing the sequence 123 at least twice. So say there is 5 occurrences of this sequence (spaces are here to make it more readable): `123 123 123 123 123`, then the content of `$1` is `123 123 123 123` (once again, the spaces are here only for readability, and it would **not** work if they were inserted in the code).

You can then replace the hit(s) with the content of `$1`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to find the first occurence of "123" at the beginning of the string and replace with an empty string.

```
var patt  = /^(123)/;
"123123123".replace(patt, "")
"12312345435".replace(patt, "")
```

For more information check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: What if the value is `123456`? Exactly, your regex would trim `123` while it should not.